# Jest - ReferenceError: SVGPathElement is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, amcharts4

I'm trying to run a Jest unit test to match snapshot, but there seems to be an issue with am4core.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Test:
[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWKpE.png)

Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE1wC.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVGPathElement doesn’t exist on the node. It exists on the browser. Hence add this test

```
class SVGPathElement extends HTMLElement {}
window.SVGPathElement = SVGPathElement

describe('your test', () => {
```

Comment: This worked for my TS config: `window['SVGPathElement'] = SVGPathElement as any;`